# Implementing database search

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, search, select

I use mysql as database where I store my data.

I have a windows form with textboxes radiobuttons, comboboxes and more; where people give personal information about themselves like (first name, last name, sex, date birthday, phone, father name and more like this). (40 fields total)

I want to do a search button. With this button I want to fill some fields and after I push the search button a new window be opened containing all people with same personal information. I achieved to do a search button for one field (for example searching only by name).

But I have a problem when I select to search with more than one fields. For example I select to search all people who have name:Chris, Nickname:Dung, sex:Male, Birth_Country:UK and other but when I push search it gives back a window with irrelevant with the search data. Can someone help me with that?

The code I made for the search button after changes is:

```
public MySqlDataAdapter da;
public DataSet ds;
public string sTable = "data";

private void anazitisi_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            try
            {
                conn = openconnectio.GetConn();

                string radiob = null;                               
                if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
                {
                    radiob = radioButton1.Text;
                }
                else if(radioButton2.Checked == true)
                {
                    radiob = radioButton2.Text;
                }

                StringBuilder Query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM data d INNER JOIN country c ON d.id_data = c.id_country WHERE 1=1 ");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                    Query.Append(" AND name like '" + textBox1.Text + "'");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
                    Query.Append(" AND lastname like '" + textBox2.Text + "'");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radiob))
                    Query.Append(" AND sex like '" + radiob + "'");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox1.Text))
                    Query.Append(" AND birthdate like '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "'");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox2.Text))
                    Query.Append(" AND phone_number like '" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "'");

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query.ToString(), conn);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, sTable);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                DataGridView dg1 = new DataGridView();
                form2.Controls.Add(dg1);
                dg1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                dg1.Refresh();
                dg1.DataSource = ds;
                dg1.DataMember = sTable;

                form2.Show();

                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

My results after search is fine when i comment that code:
(birthdate code) and i dont used as search of course.

```
        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox1.Text))
        //    Query.Append(" AND birthdate like '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "'");
```

But when i use the (birthdate code) i get us result only a blank row.
**I think** because the birthdate maskedTextbox have a mask: 00/00/0000
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Why you are usign too many `LIKE` using? This can slow down a MYSQL performance. Use MATCH/AGAINST instead.

Comment: can you show us a formatted SQL query? Are you only adding parameters if they selected an item, it may be searching for matches with `blank` values which is where you're getting the irrelevant results

Comment: Your query is full of OR statements that will match a null value and spit it back.  You need a query that's more specific on what you want, ignoring nulls, so you get an accurate search instead of taking everything in the table.  You should also rework your join and remove ambiguity.  `SELECT * FROM data d INNER JOIN country c ON d.id_data = c.id_country WHERE ....` will help other's read your code

Comment: @MattBusche What do you mean by showing you a formatted SQL query?
I am asking because i am new in programming.

Comment: @JustAguy Thank you for your advise. I know the problem with OR but i dont know how to replace OR with something else. Do you have an advice or an example about with what i must replace OR? It would be appreciated.

Comment: @Chris If your query ends up being WHERE name LIKE '%%' OR firstname LIKE '%%' then that's the issue. Can't tell if you're passing in every form field option whether a value was entered or not

Comment: 1 - Yo forget to add AND keyword, you must use  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                Query.Append(" And name like '" + textBox1.Text); 2- da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Qery.Tostring()) will do the rest

Comment: @M.Heydari I wanna thank you first and sorry about my mistake, I replace the code and i get an error at 
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query.Tostring());   
Error : 'System.Text.StringBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Tostring' and no extension method 'Tostring' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Any idea?

Comment: Use Qery.ToString() pal

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection - it isn't just about web applications. By glueing parameters into your query in this way, you make it very easy for anyone who can get into your application to do bad stuff - for instance, if they enter '; drop database; into the name fields, your database gets dropped.

Comment: @M.Heydari When i use da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Qery.Tostring());
Have an error: The name 'Qery' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @NevilleK Thanks for the advice Neville i will keep it mind.

Comment: @M.Heydari Thanks Heydari for your help, i have just a problem with birthdate i think because i use a mask: 00/00/0000. 
Any idea?
Thanks again!

Comment: first: you must not use "LIKE" operator in every condition you have, for example you need to use "=" in birthdate Second: AND birthdate =    '" + Date.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text) + ... Third: you have not marked my Answer as Answer of your your question ;)

Comment: @M.Heydari First: When you say marked your Answer as Answer of my question you mean the check icon? 
Second: When i use the code:                 
(" AND birthdate = '" + DateTime.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text) + "'");
I get an unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
And as additional information:The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. When i declare the birthdate in mysql i do it as VARCHAR. Are you think that's the problem? Thanks

Comment: 1- yes :) 2- I prefer using a DateTimePicker control instead of maskedTextBox1 3- Dear @Chris you have to review some codes on google or codeProject.com, do not try to learn basic concepts here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should consider three things
**1-** You may replace **OR** with **And** in your query 
 
   I mean instead of using

```
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(
"SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN country ON id_data = id_country 
 WHERE name like '" + textBox1.Text + 
"'OR lastname like '" + textBox2.Text + 
"'OR sex like '" + radiob + 
"'OR birthdate like '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + 
"'OR phone
_number like '" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "' ;", conn);
```

You may use

```
 da = new MySqlDataAdapter(
 "SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN country ON id_data = id_country 
 WHERE name like '" + textBox1.Text + 
 "'AND lastname like '" + textBox2.Text + 
 "'AND sex like '" + radiob + 
 "'AND birthdate like    '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + 
 "'AND phone_number like '" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "' ;", conn);
```

**2-** You have to build your query string based on your text boxes and else seeing if they have any value, something like this:

```
StringBuilder Query = "SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN country ON id_data = id_country 
     WHERE 1=1 ";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
  Query.Append(" AND name like '" + textBox1.Text);
....
```

**3-** [Sql Injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @Chris This one fits in with your current code and further refines the query.  However it may be too restrictive on it's matching.  Give this a shot and see what you come out with.

Comment: @JustAguy Well i changed the code. I changed OR with AND but now i have to fill all the fields to get a result. When i fill only the name field i get nothing as a result. What i have to do if i want to get all the people with name = Chris for example??

Comment: @Chris if a form field was not filled in then you need to not add that to your SQL query - option 2 of M.Heydari's answer covers this

Answer (score -1):

oh my God !!! Some programming !!!

where clause must created by and/or ,... other clauses , 
so ,

two solutions exist : 
On server Side by Store Procedure by below definition :
you must care by position of AND/OR in below :

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo_Bank_SELByFields] 
(
  @ID  nvarchar(50)  = NULL , 
  @BankName   nvarchar(50)  = NULL , 
  @BankCode   nvarchar(50)  = NULL , 
  @Address   nvarchar(50)  = NULL , 
  @BranchCode   nvarchar(50)  = NULL  
)
AS 
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bank WHERE 
( 
 (@ID  IS NULL OR ID = @ID) AND
 (@BankName  IS NULL OR BankName =@BankName) AND
 (@BankCode  IS NULL OR BankCode =@BankCode) AND
 (@Address  IS NULL OR Address =@Address) AND
 (@BranchCode  IS NULL OR BranchCode =@BranchCode)  
) ORDER BY BankCode

//---you know call the Sp  . OK?
```

and other solution  in your business layer code  : 
if you use ORM such as Entity Framework , very easy By IQueryable object, you can use below :

```
 var selectByEnyCondition=(from c in ctx.customer ...);
 //---- you must add by below way : 
 if(!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)))
 {
    selectByEnyCondition.Where(.....);
 }
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sex))
 {
  selectByEnyCondition= opportunites.Where(.....);
 }
 //------ 
 /* **** beacuse you use by ADO.NET technique you should use StringBuilder -->*/
  StringBuilder query;
  query.add("SELECT * FROM BankTbl WHERE ");

  if(!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))){ 
   query.Add("Name Like {0}",txtName.Text); 

  //-----now continue for build your criteria
```

king reguard
bye.....

Comment: @Chris The two answers above both have merit in their approach.  The stored procedure here is a very good alternative if you want to return null value match but that's not really the idea behind a search.  It also introduces you to another area of complexity, stored procedure programming, and being a beginner these approaches will overwhelm you.

Comment: @sarshong eng. Can you do an example with my variables?
Because i can't understand exactly what you want to do.
(Sorry i am new in programming).

Comment: Ok sir, I change this response by your variable and please
also if it useful you can set score for response to this fourm